# HDD not detected in the BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, bios

So, I have a system with an SSD that I use as a system disk (boot + windows + programs) and 2 HDD: a 1.5TB and 1TB.

Suddenly, the 1.5 TB disappeared from windows! So I took a look in disk management and it did not appear. Intrigued, I restarted, went into the BIOS ... and it did not appear !!

So I tried stuff like connecting with other SATA cables (including those of 1TB which works), but still not detected!

I tried to connect it to another computer and BIOS detects the 1TB but not the 1.5 TB.

The disk doesn't make any suspicious noise though

So, I'm screwed right? :(

Comment: You can send it to a professional to see if the data is recoverable, but it is not cheap for SSD's.

Comment: `Suddenly, the 1.5 TB disappeared from windows! `. It is the 1.5T HDD which failed. Not the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I'm screwed right? :(

Probably. Your disk is not visible in the BIOS on at least two computers, while others drives do work. That rules out motherboard problems. You tried other cables.  That only leaves the drive as a point of failure.

> The disk doesn't make any suspicious noise though

It could be the electronics part which failed. While mechanical faults seem more common they are not the only things which can fail.

As it is the only solution seem to be to buy a new drive and restore data from backup.

Comment: If only I had a backup ! Haha fortunately trhere was nothing important on that disk...I think

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  If all you are interested in is recovering data from the drive, you can use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the files from the disc, provided it is not seriously damaged.

You would just download the appropriate version (which, would be any of the Windows executables), extract it from the zip file, and run it in Administrative Command Line.

After that, you would select the disk that is having issues, the partition the files are in, and you should then see the root directory of the file system.  To copy a file/folder, you can use the on-screen prompts to select them (`:` to select a file/folder, or `c` to copy now), and then select the destination of said file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The HDD is not visible at all. Not to the OS, not in the BIOS.  There is nothing to run testdisk on.

Comment: I've used TestDisk on drives that would not show up in either, but still able to recover data from them.

Comment: Even when not showing up in the BIOS? I saw no hint of that in their FAQ or in wikipedia. Closest I could find was "TestDisk queries the BIOS or the operating system in order to find the data storage devices (hard disks, memory cards, …) and their characteristics ".  So it should work even if not mountable in the OS, but that is different from not even showing up in the BIOS.

Comment: Yeah, as expected, it doesn't see the missing disk ... You've probably used TestDisk on devices who wouldn't show up in windows but showed in the bios ...

Comment: I felt it was worth a shot.

Actually, Linux; I tend to use Windows only when I have to.

Comment: You're welcome.  Sorry it didn't help though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that, but since the drive doesn't appear when you connect it to another PC, then my suggestion will be to consult with a professional data recovery specialist if you want to retrieve your information from the drive. Usually the manufacturers have a number of data recovery partners listed in their website, so you can check there and see if there is one near you.

For instance, here are the WD partners:

http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=4suzeL

I hope you get all the data back from the HDD and best of luck!